# Sharepoint 2010 + ContentType + Multilingue Document Template

Tags: content-type, multilingual, document-template

I like to know if is possible to associate multiple DocumentTemplates into a ContentType?

I create a ContentType "MY_CONTENTTYPE", so if i have 3 documents with the same content but in 3 different languages (PT FR EN) i need to create "MY_CONTENTTYPE_PT","MY_CONTENTTYPE_FR" and "MY_CONTENTTYPE_EN"? Or is possible to associate the 3 documents to the same contenttype?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is create a parent content type ("MY Content Type") and then create 3 children

MyContentTypePT MyContentTypeEN MyContentTypeFR

You can manage the fields for all three with MyContentType but associate a different template to each.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is... No :(

You can develop some features that can give you the choice of your template in a custom TargetName Url, but built-in, there is no option...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to my answer above is to use the Dark Blue Duck [Template Enabler](http://www.darkblueduck.com/Products/TemplatesEnabler2010.aspx).